# Can I use @media query max-width for responsive when make a page for large device?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I make a portfolio page, but I just make for large device. Now I want responsive so can I use @media query?

Here is my page, it looks good in large device but medium device and mobile look bad:
http://khanh19934.github.io/demofullport/
example

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas to get you started.

Begin by adding a viewport meta tag in the head of your page, this will instruct mobile devices not to scale the content to fit the viewport (window width)

```
<head> 
... 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
...
<head/>
```

Then you need to examine all elements on the page and adjust them where necessary so they work for all screen widths.

One approach would be to start with a wide window, then decrease the width until something doesn't look good. At that point inspect and adjust the css for the element in question.

You'll probably create a media query which targets the element at that viewport.

For example, you might decide that when the viewport is 1000px wide, the title div in the centre of your page is too small, it's currently styled at 25%, so you create a media query like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
 #title{
   width:50%;
 }
}
```

If you are new to responsive design spend some time getting up to speed with [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/) and what you can do with it. It's indispensable for work like this.

Good luck!